# real world coordinates calculation using one camera

Tags: python, opencv, camera, projection, camera-calibration

Does anyone know if the following is possible with only one camera:

I am trying to determine the real coordinates of 3 objects (size known) located somewhere in an area of 10 by 3 meters , on the ground. I can already determine the coordinates in the picture of the objects. The camera hangs 2.5 m high from the ceiling.

Can I do this with one camera or do I need two cameras anyway?

I tried to calculate the distance using the focal length of my camera.

Comment: Do you know the focal length of the camera?  Is the camera pointing straight downward? Are all objects on the ground plane? If all are true, then you can get the coordinates.

Comment: What is "real world coordinates" you said?
If it is "on Camera coordinate system", you will be able to estimate distance to object(from camera) based on the known object size. If you want "on other coordinate system", camera's extrinsic parameter will be needed, additionally.

Comment: If you want estimate the distance based on "on the ground", what you need is camera's extrinsic parameter(related to the ground).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one camera suffices.

Specifically, you could use AR markers. OpenCV comes with "aruco".

The task is generally called "pose estimation". It requires you to have a 3D model of the object, i.e. to know the edge length of the AR marker square.

If the camera's lens is sufficiently non-warping, you don't even *need* to perform complex calibration. Just estimate the focal length (pixels), which you can do given an object's physical distance and physical width (meters), and apparent width (pixels).